# Why Isn't Netbeans not giving me an option to create a html project when I click ' New Project'?

Tags: html, netbeans

I haven't a clue as to why I can't select html5 application for a new project on Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

*"Sorry, the SE bundle you downloaded doesn't include HTML5, but you can add it by selecting Tools->Plugins, select the "Available Plugins" tab, click on "Name" to sort by name, scroll down to the HTML selections, check them all, Click "Install". Note: The EE and ALL bundles carry HTML5, but not the SE bundle."*... source : http://w.planetnetbeans.org/post-152779.html ;)